# D3 Chord Diagram Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: d3.js

Using the excellent guide by [Nadieh Bremer](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/c11409af47b5950f0289) I'm making a stretched chord diagram.
However, with certain data inputs the rendering goes awry.

I've made a demo to demonstrate my issue here:
https://codepen.io/benmayocode/pen/MPEwdr

Specifically, in the .js file lines 269 to 281 file I have:

```
var respondents = 40,
    emptyPerc = 0.4,
    emptyStroke = Math.round(respondents*emptyPerc); 
var Names = ['BEN', 'ROSE', '', '1', '2', '6', ''];
var matrix = [
[0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0] ,
[0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0] ,
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24] ,
[10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
[10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
[0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
[0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0] ,
];
```

This renders incorrectly - but if I change it to...

```
var respondents = 40,
    emptyPerc = 0.4,
    emptyStroke = Math.round(respondents*emptyPerc); 
var Names = ['BEN', 'LIB', 'ROSE', '', '1', '2', '6', ''];
var matrix = [
[0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0, 0] ,
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0] ,
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 0] ,
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24] ,
[10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
[10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
[0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
[0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0] ,
];
```

Then it works great. I obviously see the difference between the two blocks of code, but why are they producing different results, and is it possible to modify my code to accommodate both examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the dodgy arc, you will see you can flip it into the right place by altering the sign on the transform from `(50,0)` to `(-50,0)`. If you then look at the code that assigns the transform, it is

```
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    d.pullOutSize = pullOutSize * ( d.startAngle + 0.01 > Math.PI ? -1 : 1);
    return "translate(" + d.pullOutSize + ',' + 0 + ")";
});
```

with a note in the original text to say that "the 0.01 is for rounding errors". Given that the `startAngle` is already 3.13--i.e. very close to Pi--it looks like this is an edge case where the value fell just the wrong side of the cutoff. Changing the allowable rounding error value to 0.02 puts the arc in the correct place, or you could do something like

```
d.pullOutSize = pullOutSize * ( 
    // is the start angle less than Pi?
    d.startAngle + 0.01 < Math.PI ? 1 :
    // if yes, is the end angle also less than Pi?
        d.endAngle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1 );
```

to prevent edge cases like that in your dataset.